# How can I tidy up this short javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fade, parallax

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s1d368ce/

I am trying to get three separate headers (h1, h2, and h3) to fade out when the user scrolls down the page. I want each header to fade out slightly slower than the one above, so I have three parts to my code, as follows. However, only the last bit works (i.e. the h3 fades out but h2 and h1 don't. If I remove the last section for h3, then h2 fades out but h1 does not. And if I remove the h3 and h2 javascript then h1 fades out.)

I wonder if anyone could show me how to re-organize the code so that it works?

Please see my code demo; only the code for h3 works. But, if I were to remove the 'scroll-fade-long-2' section of the javascript code, then h2 would fade out, but not h1. ??

Thank you so much!

```js
jQuery(function($){  
//Scroll fade
  var divs = $('.scroll-fade');
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 
    'margin-top' : -(st/3)+"px", 
    'opacity' : 1 - st/135
          }); 
  });
  
  //Scroll fade long
  var divs = $('.scroll-fade-long');
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 
    'margin-top' : -(st/3)+"px", 
    'opacity' : 1 - st/255
   }); 
  });


  //Scroll fade long2
  var divs = $('.scroll-fade-long-2');
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 
    'margin-top' : -(st/3)+"px", 
    'opacity' : 1 - st/355
   }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="scroll-fade">header 1</h1>
<h2 class="scroll-fade-long">header 2</h2>
<h3 class="scroll-fade-long-2">header 3</h3>



<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/ocntm9tx/4/) EDIT: updated the opacity. Did a quick copy paste. Works.

You only need to call the `$(window).on('scroll', function(){});` once.

```
var sf = $('.scroll-fade');
var sfl = $('.scroll-fade-long');
var sfl2 = $('.scroll-fade-long-2');

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    sf.css({
        'opacity' : 1 - st/135,
        'margin-top': -(st/3)+"px"
    });
    sfl.css({
        'opacity' : 1 - st/255,
        'margin-top': -(st/3)+"px"
    });
    sfl2.css({
        'opacity' : 1 - st/355,
        'margin-top': -(st/3)+"px"
    });
});
```

Also see Miro's compact solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ocntm9tx/5/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
        $('.scroll-fade-'+i).css({
            'opacity' : 1 - st/(i*100),
            'margin-top': -(st/3)+"px"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This actually isn't nearly as efficient as OP code. Since `scroll` event occurs many times a second;  caching the collections the way OP did is far more performant since it doesn't require all the needless DOM searching

Comment: I wasn't trying to make it more efficient. "Please see my code demo; only the code for h3 works. But, if I were to remove the 'scroll-fade-long-2' section of the javascript code, then h2 would fade out, but not h1. ??" Just answered his question.

Comment: Just pointing out that it could be greatly improved for performance and is not a solid answer as it is. I rephrase that it isn't as efficient as OP's approach

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: definitely, only thing now would be it is redundant to wrap an existing jQuery object in `$()`..can simply do `sf1.css(...`

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even notice that.

Comment: Here's an even more compact version based on @Grimbode 's answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/ocntm9tx/5/